# Test Jenkins 2.0 Pipeline but does nothing

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2

I try to execute the example of Jenkins for a new Pipeline.
When I launch it, the build is running but when I display the console, there is nothing in it except `Started by user anonymous`
I let the pipeline run for a few minutes and then I force to kill it.

As I said, I try the demo script in Jenkins:

```
node {
   stage 'Stage 1'
   echo 'Hello World 1'
   stage 'Stage 2'
   echo 'Hello World 2'
}
```

Comment: I installed Jenkins 2.0 and the this plugin with all it's dependencies: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin

Comment: Are you able to execute any other project?

Comment: I did not try for a Pipeline project but it works well for CI for other Maven projects

Comment: Try running Pipeline job from fresh JENKINS_HOME or get more information using [Support Core Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Support+Core+Plugin).

Comment: I re-installed all the pipeline plugin and restart Jenkins. I installed Support Core Plugin too but I don't where to look at to have input of what's going on... Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution.

As I said in the question, I had to install (manually) the pipeline plugin and all its dependencies because I was under a proxy and I haven't at this time the credentials to pass through it.

Today I had the credentials and I let Jenkins do an update of all of my plugins and everythings went fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can check a thread dump and the Jenkins log file. Something is badly broken but from the description alone it is impossible to say what.